# How to Handle A Static Variable on Concurrent Request's in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have Static Object using in WCF Service Method where now i need to Handle Concurrent Request's on this Static Object .

Please Suggest me how can i achieve this without modifying Static Objects, Since it makes me to redesign the Entire Project.

```
public static Cont Cont 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return m_contextStorage.Context; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        Context ctx = m_contextStorage.Context; 
        ctx = value; 
        m_contextStorage.Context = ctx; 
    } 
}
```

This is the object which I will be added some data for every request, but what's the issue is when still the Request 1 is processing the function now the Reqeust 2 has entered now it is overriding the Request-1 Object Data. Since it is Static.

Comment: Some more infos would be helpful.

Comment: public static Cont Cont
        {
            get { return m_contextStorage.Context; }
            set
            {
                Context ctx = m_contextStorage.Context;
                ctx = value;
                m_contextStorage.Context = ctx;
            }
        }   this is the object which i will be added some data for every request, but what's the issue is when still the Request 1 is processing the function now the Reqeust 2 has entered now it is overriding the Request-1 Object Data. Since it is Static

Comment: I think you'll still need to provide a bit more code to illustrate your problem. `m_contextStorage.Context` is a database-context, isn't it? Why does it have to be shared? And even worse: Why is there a setter? Is it necessary that the context is written back after usage? You could use a [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to sync the usage, but I really think a redesign would be a better idea...

Comment: It's generally better to let WCF handle instance creation (in this case `Singleton`) and put the DB context in the WCF service class rather than doing so manually.  Note that an `AppDomain`-wide DB context is probably a bad idea if your service is **concurrent**.  Maybe make your service `PerSession` with the context per session rather than static?